# Integral with error function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, error-function

If $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ independent and I have to compute $\mathbb{P}(X+Y<z)-\mathbb{P}(X+Y<0)$, I write:

$=[[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy]\cdot [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{z-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx]]-[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy]\cdot [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx]=$ ...

Thus, for the first probability:

… = $[…]\cdot [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{z-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx]=[…]\cdot [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{z-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx]=[…]\cdot [\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{z-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx]$

How can I solve the last integral?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X+Y\sim N(0,2)$. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}(X+Y< z)-\mathsf{P}(X+Y< 0)=\Phi(z/\sqrt{2})-1/2.
$$